# $F$ is a field such that for every $a\in F, a^4=a$, then what is the characteristic of $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

$F$ is a field such that for every $a\in F, a^4=a$, then what is the characteristic of $F$?

Take any $a,b \in F-\{0\}$. then $(a+b)^4=a+b\implies a+b +4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3=a+b\implies 4a+4b+6a^2b^2=0$.

Multiplying throughout by $ab$ and using $a^3=b^3=1$, we get $4a^2+4b^2+6=0$. I am not sure how to go from here. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You have a polynomial equation of second degree in for example $a$. If $4\neq 0$ then it has at most two solutions. If $F$ has at least $3$ elements this cannot hold. And so $4=0$ which already implies characteristic $2$.

Comment: @freakish But the equation has degree $4$, not $2$, and it holds in the field with $4$ elements.

Comment: Since every element of the field satisfies $a^4-a=0$ there can be at most four elements (the equation has at most four roots) so there are not many cases to check.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm referring to the final equation OP reached by himself: $4a^2+4b^2+6=0$. It is of degree $2$. Besides I'm not sure how would you conclude $4=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @freakish I think the easiest approach is to say that $a^4=a$ for all $a \in F$ immediately implies that $|F| \le 4$, and then you can check the fields of orders $2,3,4$ individually and observe that the equation does not hold in ${\mathbb F}_3$.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible only when $-1=1$, otherwise $(-1)^4=1\neq-1$.
For the example in the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ the identity $a^4=a$ holds.

Comment: There are many other fields where it holds.

Comment: @ancientmathematician But they all have the same characteristic because $-1=1$

Comment: This is pretty much a complete answer to the question if you additionally note what $-1=1$ means for the characteristic.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: could you elaborate? Since $a^3=1$ on $F^{\times}$, $F$ can only be $\mathbb{F}_2$ or $\mathbb{F}_4$…

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @Aphelli I am sorry, by "it" I meant the statement "$-1=1$".

Comment: @ancientmathematician: Well, by "this identity" I meant the identity $a^4=a$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I figured it out:

We have $(-a) ^4= a^4$ so $-a= a$ for every $a$. It follows that $2a=0$,hence the field is of char $2$.